# React Native Fetching New Data From Mysql DB

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, react-native-navigation

i'm newbie in React Native, i just want to ask something about fetching a new data after i press delete button. I was try this code, but if i press the delete button the data still available on the screen but it was deleted on my database. Is it a bug or error ? and what should i do to make the data gone from the screen ?

```
DeleteUsers = () => {
  fetch('http://192.168.43.67/crudPHP/delete.php',
    {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ id: this.state.TextInputId })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      Alert.alert(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.error(error); })
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Second')
}


render(){
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1, alignItems: "center", marginTop: 5,
      backgroundColor: '#fff'
    }}>
      <TextInput
        value={this.state.TextInputNama}
        placeholder='Masukan Nama'
        onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ TextInputNama: TextInputValue })}
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        style={styles.TextInputStyle1}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={this.state.TextInputEmail}
        placeholder='Masukan Email'
        onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ TextInputEmail: TextInputValue })}
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        style={styles.TextInputStyle2}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={this.state.TextInputPhoneNumber}
        placeholder='Masukan Nomor Telepon'
        onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.setState({ TextInputPhoneNumber: TextInputValue })}
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        style={styles.TextInputStyle2}
      />

      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.4} style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} onPress={this.UpdateUsers}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Update Data</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.4} style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyleDel} onPress={this.DeleteUsers}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Delete</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error, but a logical bug. Your data has been deleted from the database but your local data is still on the device so it is being shown. You should clear that once the remote data is successfully deleted.

Comment: Hmm.. i think so, but how to remove local data from my device and the data in database at the same time ?? @surajmalviya

Comment: Well that depends on how you have stored the data and used to show. Can you edit your question to show that  so that I can further help ?